# Scientific literature citation for the blob detection algorithm in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, citations

I have been using the Simple Blob Detection algorithm from the OpenCV library (for Python) for a research project. I would like to reference this particular method algorithm in my paper.

Does anyone know from where this method is from and indicate me a good to reference to cite? The openCV source code does not refer to any particular literature.

Thanks

Comment: I can't vote delete, as there is a bounty, but I believe this question is blatantly off-topic in stackoverflow. Asking about scientific references for algorithms is asking someone to Google/research for you. This should (and I believe is) off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the [Connected-component labeling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

Comment: That's not true. Connected component is just [one step](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#simpleblobdetector) of the algorithm